# VSE questions (playback, proxies, etc..)

Tags: edit-mode

When you drag and drop footage in the VSE, is there a way to have audio and video linked in order not to have to select audio and video + G key everytime moving files in the VSE? Preview window struggles to play 2K and 4K footage smoothly despite frame dropping checked and a fast desktop computer. Any way to get smooth playback without proxies? Playback at the 1/4 of the resolution for example? If this isn't possible, is there a way to generate proxies in a batch way?

Comment: Hi, please only ask 1 question at a time. You are welcome to post multiple, specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the frame dropping by increasing the following values in the *[User Preferences](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences/System)*.

[image]

To move video and audio track as one unit select both and combine them to a [meta strip](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Sequencer/Usage) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>.

[image]